# How can i read a text file word by word (seperate spaces and new lines)

Tags: c++

i am doing c++. if i have string like "word by word\n this is test", it is possible to have whitespace, word, and new line character each time ifstream get values from a text file.  like

```
string msg = "word by word\n this is test";
string eachWord;
while( // something here ) {
    // do some code here to get word by word
    // but it should get white space and new line when it hits them
}
```

so while the string "eachWord" goes through the while loop, it will have like the following

1st eachWord : "word"
 2nd eachWord : "\0" 
 3rd eachWord : "by"
.
.
.
.
.
.

NOTE: you don't know what string you will have because i will get string from a random text file

I can do it with ifstream.get() and a bunch of conditional statements but i am just wondering if there is better way.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, indicate where you have questions/doubts in your code.

Comment: @RSahu Perhaps I shouldn't have provided an answer given your comment but I was curious to try to make a solution. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: If it the text file and you read it line by line how \n could be appeared in the middle?

Comment: @JamesAdkison, that's fine. No need to delete your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `operator>>` function on the input stream and disable skipping white space characters.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ifs;
    ifs.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    ifs.str("word by word\n this is test");

    std::string word;
    char ws;
    bool isWord = false;

    // Keep reading words or if that fails clear the error state and read a white space character
    while ((isWord = static_cast<bool>(ifs >> word)) || (ifs.clear(), ifs >> ws))
    {
        std::cout << "word: '";
        if (isWord)
            std::cout << word;
        else
            std::cout << ws;
        std::cout << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
word: 'word'
word: ' '
word: 'by'
word: ' '
word: 'word'
word: '
'
word: ' '
word: 'this'
word: ' '
word: 'is'
word: ' '
word: 'test'
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Ob8ZXV)

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr or find functions to find spaces or other characters that you want.

For example:

```
string str="We think in generalities, but we live in details.";
string str2 = str.substr (3,5);  // output --> "think"
```

please read these pages it will help you:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok. In my opinion, there isn't a need to build a class around tokenizing unless strtok doesn't provide you with what you need. Here is an example

```
char myString[] = "Word1 Word2"; 
char *p = strtok(myString, " ");

while (p) { 
    printf ("Token: %s\n", p);
    p=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

A few caveats (which might not suit your needs). The string is "destroyed" in the process, meaning that EOS characters are placed inline in the delimter spots. Correct usage might require you to make a non-const version of the string. You can also change the list of delimiters mid parse.

Answer (score 0):

Full c++ solution based on orbitcowboy suggestion.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>    words;

    std::ifstream ifs("words.txt");
    if (ifs.is_open() == false)
    { std::cerr << "Couldn't open file..." << std::endl; return -1; }

    std::string string_to_split(
                 (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs))
                 , std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    char * cstr = new char [string_to_split.length()+1];
    std::strcpy (cstr, string_to_split.c_str());

    const char delimiters[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    char *p = strtok(cstr, delimiters);
    while (p) {
        words.push_back(p);
        words.push_back("");
        p = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    for (auto word : words)
    { std::cout << "word: " << word << std::endl; }
}
```

Note that this is higlhy inneficient for huge files due to the way I create string_to_split.

This uses a c++11 feature at the end `for (auto sentence : sentences)`, remove it if you don't compile with c++11 flag.